# How to append additional element in JSON Array using power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, json

I have a SharePoint list having a Notes and another NotesHistory field. Every time user puts some note that should get appended with the NotesHistory field and the original Notes field gets reset.

Requirement is to store the notes in JSON string array as below.
[{"Date":"16/3/2021","Notes":"This is a sample note1"},{"Date":"16/3/2021","Notes":"This is a sample note2"}]

So, each time the notes gets added how would I append the {"Date":"16/3/2021","Notes":"This is a sample note3"} to the above JSON array retrieved from the current list item using Power Automate

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either use **[Append to array variable]** action or **union()** function like `union(variables('arrayNotes'), variables('arrayNoteItem'))` to add a new item to the original array.

See the screenshots below.

[image]

**Using Union function**

[image]

Comment: @Matiur_Rahman, this is great info. I didn't know `union` was so powerful. Thank you